# Form based Login Authentication for Public Site Sharepoint online

Tags: custom, login

I'm really new to SharePoint coding but have little understanding although this little understanding is not enough to execute the concepts.

I'm looking for a custom (form based) login for my online SharePoint public site.
If anyone has some ready made sample which I can use easily would be really a great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option on this is to setup/configure ADFS.

### Regards..Antelope

Ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/029dac11-fc0d-457d-9f35-4a0eebb1dd1c/sharepoint-online-2013-custom-user-login-page?forum=sharepointadmin